# ASP.NET Web API - use for AJAX request handling or not?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, owin, katana

In the book "[Pro ASP.Net Web Api Security](http://amzn.com/1430257822)" by Badrinarayanan Lakshmiraghavan the author states (At the end of Chapter 1):

> Caution: ASP.NET Web API is meant for developing web APIs. In other
>   words, although it can technically work, it is not the right candidate
>   for supplementing your web application's AJAX needs, especially when
>   the AJAX use cases are very few.

Can you please postulate on the author's perspective? 
Specifically - how [this tutorial from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx) seems to contradict the notion that Web API Shouldn't be used to serve AJAX.

I am trying to define an OWIN/Katana tech-stack and am having a hard time discovering which component is most suitable for what.

Comment: I think I almost understand what he means. For flexible return types (JSON/XML) then yes its good and works fairly well with ajax, but for using weird authentication methods that ajax can't natively keep with (unless you use a jquery cookie plugin), it turns into a really painful experience. Now, I agree Web Apis and RESTful services should be good to work with Ajax, and I disagree that 'use casses are very few'.